# Access Calendar Item of shared calendar on Outlook

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins

I have been struggling over this for some time now.

**What do I need:**
I need to open calendar item of a user who has shared his/her calendar with me.

**What I have done so far**:

So I have a userA who wants to access to UserB's calendar event and edit it.
To access the item, first thing I did is, make UserB share its calendar with User A and give edit permission like below

[image]

Now this userA (test1 on pic) have full access. I go ahead and create a new meeting on User B's calendar. Then I open fiddler and grad the event ID from Response:

[image]

I am running an add-in on UserA mailbox that has 1 button and onclick it calls

```
Office.context.mailbox.displayAppointmentForm(itemId)
```

When I click it, as you may expect I get the event details like below:

[image]

Everything is smooth so far. Now I go ahead and click Edit. Since I gave the edit permission , I am expecting to be able to edit it. I go ahead and click edit and this is what I get:

[image]

**The action could not be completed. Access denied error.**

I thought may be it is permission issue, may be giving it edit does not really let it to edit. So I tried giving User A full permission over user B's Mailbox - Not just calendar, whole mailbox- but that did not solve it either.

I have been in contact with Microsoft Dev Chat but unfortunately they could not reproduce my situation, and it seemed to work for them smoothly.

Love to hear some insights and hopefully a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Outlook add-ins are not fully supported in shared calendars/mailboxes. However, this is a feature that we are currently investigating.

Comment: We raised a ticket and turns out, like you said, displayAppointmentForm doesn’t support this scenario. Apparently it can be done using EWS API but I am not sure if that will give me the dialog box that displayAppointmentForm provides. The whole idea was to cut down dev time for the dialog box and use exsisting API calls

Comment: If you use the EWS API, and there's an access denial on the server, it won't give you a dialog box. Instead, you will get ErrorAccessDenied in the EWS response payload. Since shared calendars/mailboxes are not fully supported, there are other issues you might encounter.